# Sine function - merry-go-round

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, wave-equation

A merry-go-round takes 15 seconds to complete one revolution/spin. 
Within that time, each horse moves up and down five times. The vertical 
motion of the horse spans a range of 50 cm, and the horse is 1 m high at its 
vertically centre position.

a. Sketch a graph of the height of the horse over time for one complete 
revolution/spin of the ride, starting with the horse at its lowest 
position, where h is the height of the horse in centimetres and t is 
the time elapsed in seconds.

b. State the equation of the SINE function that relates the height of the 
horse, h, as a function of time, t

To Solve for the equation I did the following:

Form of equation should be  h = a sin k(t - d) + c

1m height of horse = 100 cm vertical displacement = c

Range is up/down 50 cm, hence a = 50/2 = 25

Period is 5 times up/down in 15 sec, therefore 15/5 = 3. Then 2π/k = 3. Solving for k= 2π/3

d - I am unsure

So far my equation is  h = 25 sin ( (2π/3 (t-d)) + 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

You have the equation $h=a\sin k(t-d)+c$

You have the range $a=25$

Since the it goes $5$ times up and down in $15$ seconds, $k=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$

We have $h=25\sin\bigg(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}t\bigg)+100$

But note that we need to move the curve $\dfrac34$ units in the right direction, so we get 
$$h=25\sin\bigg(\bigg(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\bigg)\bigg(t-\dfrac{3}{4}\bigg)\bigg)+100$$

Comment: thank you, how did you get 3/4?

Comment: Read the question "The vertical motion of the horse spans a range of $50$ cm, and the horse is $1$ m high at its vertically centre position"